# error using MySQLdb

Tags: python, apache, localhost, mysql-python

I am newbie to python,I have simple code to connect  database using MySQLdb and Python3.4 running in localhost.

Python Code:

```
#!c:/Python34/python.exe -u
import cgitb ,cgi
import sys
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,
                                       db='example2',
                                       user='root',
                                       password='tiger')
cursor = conn.cursor()
if conn:
   print("sucess")
```

But getting error ,while executing a code
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 4, in <module>
    password='tiger')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Please give some suggestion

Comment: Please don't edit the error out of your question. Your question is unusable now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the single quotes from the port.

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                       port=3306,
                       database='example2',
                       user='root',
                       password='tiger')
```

Comment: getting error as Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 4, in <module>
    password='tiger')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: 'password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: it's "passwd", not "password".

Comment: ohh yeah. i usually use the mysql connector from the mysql webpage and there you use password http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html